# DateTime to int c#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте,

Подскажите пожалуйста, как преобразовать переменную времени в int

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
int data = Convert.ToInt32(dt);
```

Так не работает.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете перевести текущее время в секунды или миллисекунды. Общепринятая дата отсчёта при этом является 00:00:00 01.01.1970 по UTC.

```
DateTime dt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Now);

DateTime dt1970 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

TimeSpan tsInterval = dt.Subtract(dt1970);

Int32 iSeconds = Convert.ToInt32(tsInterval .TotalSeconds);

Int64 iMilliseconds = Convert.ToInt64(tsInterval .TotalMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

[вот так - корректно](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.tofiletime.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Если устраивает точность до секунд и диапазон дат +- примерно 68 лет от 2017, то работает это решение. По необходимости можно двигать диапазон дат, меняя в коде цифру 2017 на требуемую. На всякий случай обращаю внимание, что ConvertDateTimeToInt32 по-хорошему нуждается в некой логике обработки ошибок. Сейчас при выходе даты за границу рабочего диапазона, вернет неверное значение без генерации исключения.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int now = ConvertDateTimeToInt32(DateTime.Now);
            Console.WriteLine("Сейчас " + ConvertInt32ToDateTime(now));
            Console.WriteLine("Диапазон от " + ConvertInt32ToDateTime(int.MinValue));
            Console.WriteLine("Диапазон до " + ConvertInt32ToDateTime(int.MaxValue));
            int error = ConvertDateTimeToInt32(DateTime.MaxValue);
            Console.WriteLine("Error: вместо " + DateTime.MaxValue + " выдает " + ConvertInt32ToDateTime(error));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static int ConvertDateTimeToInt32(DateTime dt)
        {
            return (int)(dt - new DateTime(2017, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
        }

        public static DateTime ConvertInt32ToDateTime(int i)
        {
            return new DateTime(2017, 1, 1).AddSeconds(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя преобразовать в данный тип. Можно только в String. Как ты собираешься преобразовывать точки в Int32? Это невозможно.

Comment: Я уже решил вопрос, это делается вот так:

TimeSpan t = (new DateTime.Now - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));
int data = (int)(t.TotalDays * 86400);

И поверь это возможно :)

Comment: Ну теперь да.

Comment: Это неверно. Значение `DateTime` не уместится в `Int32`, только в `Int64` (т.е. `long`). Поэтому корректным решением было бы использовать свойство `Ticks` http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx